# Replace even and odd recurrences of string with different strings

Tags: sed, latex

I'm aware `sed` is a way to do this, but I can't get it to work. I have a Latex file which contains mathematical expressions highlighted with `$`. I would like to convert this into MathJax code. This simply requires the odd instances of a `$` to be replaced with `\(` and the even instances of `$` to be replaced with `\)`. So

```
Here is Einstein's equation $E=mc^2$ and here is Newton's law $F=ma$
```

should become

```
Here is Einstein's equation \(E=mc^2\) and here is Newton's law \(F=ma\)
```

Note that consecutive occurences of `$` are on the same line, but there may be more than one line. I want the replacement to happen throughout the file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GNU `sed`:

```
sed -Ez 's/\$([^$]*)\$/\\(\1\\)/g'
```

Same without `-E`:

```
sed -z 's/\$\([^$]*\)\$/\\(\1\\)/g'
```

The `-z` makes GNU `sed` slurp whole input as a single line. This is an extension to the standard `sed` functionality.

Comment: Great, many thanks! In case anyone wonders, ```sed -i "" 's/\$\([^$]*\)\$/\\(\1\\)/g'```does the job on macOS

Comment: @220284 I doubt this can work if the closing `$` is on a different line, as you said it is possible. You'll need to to start your script with some `H;1h;$!d;x;` for that (if you don't have GNU `sed` and the file is not too big)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I phrased things imprecisely. See my correction above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each `$` that is immediately preceded by a word boundary by `\(`, and each `$` that is immediately followed by a word boundary by `\)`:

```
sed -e 's/\$\</\\(/g' -e 's/\>\$/\\)/g' file
```

GNU `sed` users can use `\<` and `\>` for word boundaries, but could also use `\b` instead. BSD users can use `\<` and `\>` as shown, but would be able to use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, if they wanted to (macOS users with their *default* `sed` would have to use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`).

Comment: Thanks, that's also helpful!